# Shorten an url with '#' symbol via bit.ly API

Tags: api, url, escaping, bit.ly

So, i have an url - http://somesite.com/#sometext. I need to shorten this url with the bit.ly API. The problem is, i cant properly escape the '#' symbol. **I dont get any short url's if trying to short this one with the API**. But i can simply short any other url's (without the '#').

The thing is i **can** properly shorten this url on bit.ly website and in TweetDeck (they using the API too, right?). But i cant manage to shorten it with the API.

Some suggestions?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the URL fragment (#something) before sending it to bit.ly for shortening.  URL fragment by definition won't leave the browser when submitted to the server.  Escaping it allows it to go through.  E.g. in Javascript, `escUrl = encodeURIComponent(url)` would do it.